# Python: import error message - Django

Tags: python, django, python-import

I am a newbie to python and django, so I was running a code, and I got an error message as such:

```
File "/home/mbenchoufi/brisket/../brisket/views.py", line 11, in <module>
from influence.forms import SearchForm
ImportError: No module named forms
```

A really weird thing is that I have a file called forms.py, in the influence folder, and in this file a I have a class called SearchForm.

Here's the print sys.path infos

```
['/home/mbenchoufi/brisket', '/home/mbenchoufi/src/ckanclient', '/home/mbenchoufi/src/vdm', '/home/mbenchoufi/brisket/src/mediasync', '/home/mbenchoufi/brisket/src/transparencydata', '/home/mbenchoufi/brisket/src/simplepay', '/home/mbenchoufi/brisket/src/feedinator', '/usr/lib/python2.7', '/usr/lib/python2.7/plat-linux2', '/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-tk', '/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-old', '/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload', '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages', '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages', '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/PIL', '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gst-0.10', '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gtk-2.0', '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ubuntu-sso-client', '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ubuntuone-client', '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ubuntuone-control-panel', '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ubuntuone-couch', '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ubuntuone-installer', '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ubuntuone-storage-protocol']
['/home/mbenchoufi/brisket', '/home/mbenchoufi/src/ckanclient', '/home/mbenchoufi/src/vdm', '/home/mbenchoufi/brisket/src/mediasync', '/home/mbenchoufi/brisket/src/transparencydata', '/home/mbenchoufi/brisket/src/simplepay', '/home/mbenchoufi/brisket/src/feedinator', '/usr/lib/python2.7', '/usr/lib/python2.7/plat-linux2', '/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-tk', '/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-old', '/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload', '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages', '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages', '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/PIL', '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gst-0.10', '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gtk-2.0', '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ubuntu-sso-client', '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ubuntuone-client', '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ubuntuone-control-panel', '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ubuntuone-couch', '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ubuntuone-installer', '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ubuntuone-storage-protocol']
```

Comment: Do you have a `__init__.py` file in the `influence` folder?

Comment: Yes I do have an __init__.py !

Comment: Good, that's the first thing to check. If you import *just* `influence`, what does `print influence.__file__` give you?

Comment: So I have a __init__ file. @Martjin, I created a test.py and put import influence in it, and then I run print influence.forms, and I had this message : Warning: unknown mime-type for "influence.forms" -- using "application/octet-stream"
Error: no such file "influence.forms"
 This is was I was supposed to do ?

Comment: Is the folder that contains influence the current working directory or in the PYTHON_PATH?

Comment: It is in the current working directory

Comment: @user1611830: Hrm, not sure if Django intercepts `print` statements. I meant for you to look at `influence.__file__` to see if it was something unexpected. I *think* you have another `influence` package or module that is imported instead.

Comment: I  have the same error message if I run print influence.__file__, just 'influence.forms' is replaced by influence.__file__ in the error message

Comment: Please provide the complete folder/file structure of your project

Comment: I imported exactly the structure you'll find here : https://github.com/sunlightlabs/brisket

Comment: @schacki, btw I have just run the command on the shell import influence.forms, and it seems to be recognized. But I still have the same error message when launching the project on the browser, and here's what I get launching print influence.forms : <module 'influence.forms' from 'influence/forms.pyc'>

Answer (score 0):

1. You should try export PYTHONPATH='/path/to/your/influence/folder' (or something similar depending on the shell you are using)
2. Try this stuff in the interactive [ipython](http://ipython.org) - if you get it working in there, then it is easy to get it working in the code. This is usually the best way to do, if you are a beginner.

Comment: Thanks, I am going to try and I ll let you know

Comment: @Martijn_Pieters : I tried this on the shell export PYTHONPATH=${PYTHONPATH}:home/myname/brisket/influence/, and I still got the same error message

Comment: @user1611830 : I am trying to use ipython, what kind of commands I am supposed to use ?

Comment: @user1611830, I tried ipython and I still don't know how to debugg my stuff. Could you help ?

Comment: in fact I didn't manage to use it. Sorry, I am reammy not familiar to python and django. I am still struggling installing brisket...

Comment: http://ipython.org/presentation.html

ipython is something which is useful for you in general to try out python statements before actually typing them out. whatever statements you write in python can be written in ipython. It is just a convenient interface.

Answer (score 0):

Your project structure does not follow the [Django 1.4 docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/releases/1.4/#updated-default-project-layout-and-manage-py). Your manage.py file should be one level above of settings and urls. Check that out please.

Comment: Ok, I am going to try it. Does it sounds normal that when running print influence.forms in the shell I get  : <module 'influence.forms' from 'influence/forms.pyc'>. The extension is .pyc and not .py

Comment: If the .pyc file is in sync with the .py file, it is normal that Python calls the .pyc file

Comment: I put the manage.py file in the right place. But I still have the same problem...

Comment: You might also want to take the manage.py file from Django 1.4 (I assume that your currrent manage.py file does not originate from 1.4)

Comment: I have a lot of path and a 0 error message. What info should I be aware of. I found this in the message ('/home/mbenchoufi/brisket/influence/forms.py) Btw, where can I find a Django 1.4 file type ?

Comment: I do not know by heart, where to find the manage.py in the django code, but the easiest would be to create a dummy project and take it from there with django-admin.py startproject mysite. One of the numerous path entries should be such that it can find your influence app.

Comment: That's what I did exactly, and I have the same problem, the forms module is not recognized...

Comment: please provide the result from print sys.path

Comment: Looks as expected, I give up. Final recomendation: change the title of this question or open a new one (if the change is not possible). Make clear in the title that this is about Django. You might get more specific audience.

Answer (score 0):

You **Must** ensure that `influence` is in your sys.path.

so that, `influence` can be imported.

And, in folder `influence`, there are **must** a file named `__init__.py`

for make `influence` as a package.

add the following code in your views.py

```
import sys
influence_path = FIND_OUT_INFLUENCE_PATH
sys.path.append(influence_path)

from influence_path.foo import bar
...
```

---

When you in a shell do import. As the error shows.

you **must** set the `DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE`,

---

If you still confused,

in the shell,  cd your project path, and run the `tree` command,

then post your project folder tree

Comment: I added in views.py import sys
influence_path = /my/absolute/path/to/influence
sys.path.append(influence_path) and it still doesn't work. To find the exact tree of the project, I downloaded exactly the project from https://github.com/sunlightlabs/brisket. Any idea ?

Comment: Also I set the DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE

Comment: @user1611830 I checked up the git repo, It's strange for your problem.

Comment: @user1611830  in your project root folder, do this, `python manage.py shell`  and then, `import os; print os.getcwd(); os.path.exists('influence') `

Comment: I had this answer for print os.getcwd(); : /home/myname/brisket. And for the last question I had : true. But when clearing the cache of my browser, I have an error : influence_path=/home/mbenchoufi/brisket

SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: I put directly sys.path.append('/my/absolute/path/to/influence ') and I don't have the syntax error message anymore. But I have always the same error message not finding the forms module in influence...